# Using TortoiseSVN adding 3Gb of file to Subversion and got error 413 Request Entity too large

Tags: svn, apache, tortoisesvn

Does anyone have a solution for the following error? We can not add a large file to Subversion. We are using Apache 2.2.16 and svnclient-win32-1.6.6 for Windows. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you **really** shouldn't store 3 GB files in SVN. Seriously. Small binary files are OK, but otherwise, SVN and their source control cousins are really for *source code*, not 3 GB files.

The `Entity Too Large` error is being raised by Apache. Apache 2.2 [does support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/new_features_2_2.html) files uploaded larger than 2gb, but perhaps Subversion does not, or perhaps you are running Apache on a Windows machine. In any case, your question is more suited to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Yes, maybe we will break down the files to a smaller sizes. Yes, Apache is running on a Windows machine. I will check ServerFault.Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend seeking out an alternative to storing your large files - the first question to ask is if you really need versioning for these files. Maybe a backup solution would be better, like Dropbox for something backed by Amazon S3. Regarding Apache on Windows: the link I posted indicated that >2GB file support in was only for Unix-like systems. In Windows, you probably need a 64-bit machine, Windows, and Apache. Good luck!